# How to create multiple Python scripts and run them at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a Python script that is used to find some stresses on a structure (a crane boom) when exposed to the wind from all directions. This means it creates 360 text files, 1 for each degree the structure is facing. Instead of doing 360 consecutive loops running on a single core, I want to break the task up into maybe 10 or 20 processes. Is there a way I could modify the following code so it created and ran multiple scripts with different degree ranges i.e. one script would do 0 to 20 degrees, the next 20 to 40 etc.?

```
import math
import csv
boomDirection = 0
time = 0
maxStress = 650
with open("SomeWindAndHeadingStressMatrix.csv") as f:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(f)]    

while boomDirection < 361:
    file = open("SomeWindSpeedSourceData.txt", 'r')
    data_file = open("Bolt Stress - " + str(boomDirection) + " Degrees.csv", 'w')
    line = file.readline()

    while line != '':
        try:
            if len(line.split(','))>1:                                      
                windSpeedHigh = int(int(line.split(',')[19])*1.32)
                windSpeedLow = int(int(line.split(',')[22])*1.32)
                windDirection = int(line.split(',')[14]) - boomDirection
                if windDirection < 0:
                    windDirection += 360
                stressHigh = float(data[windSpeedHigh][windDirection])
                stressLow = float(data[windSpeedLow][windDirection])
                if time % 10080 == 0:
                    data_file.write(str(time) + ', ' + str(maxStress) + ('\n'))
                    time += 0.5
                else:
                    data_file.write(str(time) + ', ' + str(round(stressHigh,1)) + ('\n'))
                    time += 0.5
                data_file.write(str(time) + ', ' + str(round(stressLow,1)) + ('\n'))
                time += 0.5                    
        except ValueError:
            pass
        line = file.readline()
    data_file.close()
    time = 0
    boomDirection = boomDirection + 1
```

Comment: You can try `multithreading` and you need to try that out once on your own to show your efforts.

Comment: You could create a parent/child program and have multiple child processes run for each script

Comment: The easiest is with `multiprocessing.Pool` - just `map` all the degrees on a function that evaluates a degree.